# commit to differentiate

Tags: phrase-usage

Shouldn't the phrase "commit to" be followed by a present participle or a noun? I wonder whether the word "differentiate" is wrong in its form.

> These studies provide further insights into how hematopoietic progenitors **commit to differentiate** into basophils or mast cells.

> Source: Science  [E-cadherin is regulated by GATA-2 and marks the early commitment of mouse hematopoietic progenitors to the basophil and mast cell fates](https://immunology.sciencemag.org/content/6/56/eaba0178)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=commit%20to%20fund%2Ccommit%20to%20funding&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccommit%20to%20fund%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccommit%20to%20funding%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccommit%20to%20fund%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccommit%20to%20funding%3B%2Cc0) shows, **commit to** only started being used in this way in about 1980. **to** is actually a preposition, so it requires a noun, however it does look like an infinitive marker, and there was a significant peak in usage followed by a bare infinitive in about 2000. Since then, it seems to be more normal to follow it by a noun or by a gerund- which is actually a noun form of a verb. The examples in the [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/commit) only include noun and gerund forms.

From a theoretical perspective, I think that you are right and this sentence should use a gerund:

> These studies provide further insights into how hematopoietic progenitors commit to **differentiating** into basophils or mast cells.

The bare infinitive does, however, still represent about a third of actual usages in all of the examples that I have checked.